# Cloud Text-to-Speech API --Syntax Error

Tags: curl, command-line, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, text-to-speech

My goal is to create a Text-to-Speech app.   I am using the [Google Quickstart Tutorial for Text-to-Speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart) .  I have followed the first 6 steps.  I am stuck in the "Synthesize audio from text" section of the tutorial.    I get errors when running the copied code from the tutorial and pasting it into the console.

**Copied code**

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{
  'input':{
    'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
  },
  'voice':{
    'languageCode':'en-gb',
    'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
    'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
  },
  'audioConfig':{
    'audioEncoding':'MP3'
  }
}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-output.txt
```

**This is the output on my console from running the code.**

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: print-access-token)

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>  'input':{
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>    'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>  },
'}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>  'voice':{
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>    'languageCode':'en-gb',
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>    'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>    'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>  },
'}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>  'audioConfig':{
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>    'audioEncoding':'MP3'
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>  }
'}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-output.txt
'}" "https:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Not sure if this his helpful but here is the output of: gcloud config list

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud config list
[core]
account = text-to-speechaccount@sage-instrument-201620.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = sage-instrument-201620

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

**Other information**
I am most familiar with Python.  I would describe my skills as beginner.  I am running window 10.

Answer (score 0):

The example looks like it was written for unix friendly systems.  These systems use the '\' to break up multiline commands.  If I remember correctly Windows uses the caret '^' to do the exact same thing.  I would try replace all of the \ in that example with ^ and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is more related to the following message: "curl: (6) Could not resolve host: print-access-token)" which is arising because Windows doesn't recognize the $variable notation, therefore, there are two ways you can proceed:

First approach:

1. Firstly, execute the command: "gcloud auth application-default print-access-token" and copy the token value to your clipboard,
2. Paste the token value directly to your curl execution, for example:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx " -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{    'input':{      'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,         based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for         touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'    },    'voice':{      'languageCode':'en-gb',      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'    },    'audioConfig':{      'audioEncoding':'MP3'    }  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt

Remove the inverted slashes() as Windows doesn't recognize quite well this kind of characters.

Second approach:

1. Execute the command already mentioned (gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) and save the value to an environment variable:

set TOKEN=the_value_of_your_token

2. Use the reference of your token environment variable in your curl call:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %TOKEN%" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{    'input':{      'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,         based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for         touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'    },    'voice':{      'languageCode':'en-gb',      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'    },    'audioConfig':{      'audioEncoding':'MP3'    }  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt